# Reporting Services Error when report deploy

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I tried to deploy SSRS report . i created a report on visual studio .. and also i configured report server configuration manager

when i try to deploy report and open this URL

http://localhost/ReportServer
this shows an error

ERROR
"**Reporting Services Error
The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. The log on failed. (rsReportServerDatabaseLogonFailed) Get Online Help
The user name or password is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007052E)
SQL Server Reporting Services"**

whereas when i click reporting services from sql and connect then connected succesfuuly but after when i left click on server name then same error shows as above on sql

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when Reporting Services (the report server) cannot connect to the "ReportServer" mssql database, It is not a problem in your report but in the server configuration.

To solve it, run the tool "Reporting Services Configuration Manager" in the PC where MSSQL and SSRS are installed, and review everything is ok.
Specially in the Database tab.

Comment: yes everything is ok .. i dont where the problem is

Comment: this shows that sql server reporting is stopped. when i try to start then i wont start @Miguel Torres

Answer (score 0):

The error "The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. The log on failed" means that:

1. The database engine that the report server catalog database host is unaccessable.
2. The Reporting Services service account has insufficient permissions to the access the report server catalog database.

So, to fix the issue, please follow these steps:

1. Make sure we are able to connect to the database engine from the report server machine.
   a) Ping the database engine server.
   b) Try to connect to the database engine using SQL Server Mananger Studio(SSMS)(If we have.). Or, create a .UDL file, try to connect the server from this UDL.
2. Use the Reporting Services Configuration Manager(RSCM) to check the service account. If the report server is on the different server with the database engine, please use a domain account instead of the local account(Built-in account). Make sure the service account has permissions in the database engine.

Final, please check if the report server is configured correctly. We can easily check that by checking if we can open the Report Manager(http:///reports).

Besides, I would suggest you to go through each steps in the RSCM to make sure the configuration is all fine.

For more information, please see:
Configuring a Report Server Installation (Reporting Services in Native Mode): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159624.aspx